# backup домашнего каталога

Tags: резервное-копирование, linux

Собралася переустановить систему, и так получилось, что до этого момента не пользовался backupом не разу, есть в домашней папке нужные документы, музыка, которые не хотелось бы терять. Как грамотно все это дело сохранить, чтобы потом с легостью можно было востановить?И самый главный вопрос, куда сделать бэкап, если я хочу сделать recovery (на флешку или в домашнюю папку)? И как потом это дело восстановить? Прошу рассписать поподробнее.

Answer (score 2):

Самый удобный и простой вариант - это завести отдельный раздел под домашнюю папку, и при переустановках его не трогать вообще. Обычно для простых бэкапов достаточно tar'а. Сохранение

```
sudo tar cvjf backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/home/*/.gvfs /home
```

восстановление

```
sudo tar -xvjf backup.tar.bz2 -C /точка_монтирования
```

Сохраняться можно из рабочей системы. При восстановлении надо загрузиться с флэшки или диска и подмонтировать раздел, где находится домашняя папка, и выполнить команду.

Comment: Большое спасибо,так и поступлю.